# My false proof that connected subspaces are path connected

Tags: general-topology

What am I doing wrong here? Somehow I reach the wrong conclusion.

Let $U$ be an connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let's consider a point $x_ 0 \in U$. Then construct the continuous function:

$$
f : [a,b] \to U \land\, f(a)=x_0
$$ 
This defines a path from $x_0$ to other points in $U$. All we need to prove is that we can find $a,b$  such that the image of this function would be the $U$ itself.

$f^{-1}f([a,b]) = [a,b]$ itself. Since in the topology of $[a,b]$, $[a,b]$ is both open and closed, then for f to preserve its continuity, $f([a,b])$ should be both open and closed. However, since $U$ is connected, it is the only nonempty clopen set in it's topology. Then $f([a,b]) = U$. So $U$ is path connected.

Comment: What is $f(\tfrac{a+b}2)$?

Comment: If you have defined $f$ (which you haven't), then $f([a,b])$ is in general not open.

Answer (score 0):

The image of an open subset by a continuous map is not always open. Example, consider a line $l$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the induced topology, $l$ is an open subset of $l$, but if $i:l\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is the canonical embedding, $i(l)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.